# Autodesk viewer offline - http-server communication to load and save files

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We run the offline viewer using the `http-server` command, how can we make it load more files other than the bubbles and to be able to send strings back to it to save as files on the file system?

Do we have to write a modified `http-server` for that? if so can we have some direction on how?

Comment: can you be a little more specific? which sample? extract?

Comment: @AugustoGoncalves this example: https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample

Comment: I tried as described on the readme: python -m SimpleHTTPServer (on the folder where the files are) and worked fine. In summary you just need to serve the folder on your localhost, there is no server side app there.

Comment: I want to load other files than the bubbles and to be able to send back strings from the viewer that will become files on file system. @AugustoGoncalves

Comment: you need to extract the bubbles from the file you have, using extract.autodesk.io, then place the files under a folder and point to it, like on this line https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/viewer-javascript-offline.sample/blob/gh-pages/index.html#L22

Comment: But that's not what I'm asking about, I know how to work with the bubbles. I want to load my own files, not code and not bubbles files, and send data from the viewer back to the local server to be saved as files. @AugustoGoncalves

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "I want to load my own files", the Forge Viewer works with bubbles (translated from different sources). If you want to show something else, you'll need to use Three.js via viewer.impl

Comment: And how can I send back data to be saved as files? @AugustoGoncalves

Comment: Viewer itself don't save any data, Model Derivative just extract (from file to Viewer)

Comment: I want to add this feature to save data as an extension or the like, how would you suggest to communicate that to the `http-server`? @AugustoGoncalves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Viewer is read-only, nothing is saved or changed on the model after the translation.

It's possible to get the current state, like zoom, perspective or position via Autodesk.Viewing.Viewer3D methods: getState() and restoreState(), but the state **is not actually saved by default**, you'll need to implement a JavaScript that communicate with your backend to POST and GET this information. [This sample extends this state](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/library-javascript-viewer-extensions/tree/master/src/Viewing.Extension.StateManager).

[Another sample](https://github.com/jeremytammik/roomedit3d) extend this to save changes on model back to server that comunicate to the original file. Again, everything is custom implemented.

In any case you'll need a back-end that store the changes and a JavaScript that read and restore it.